# List<Model> in EditorFor not incremented properly

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, enums

I have a View that contains an Model, this model contains a list(of another Model) and this list is filled in my view with Dynamic repeating fields;

Model:

```
 public class CAOEntry
{
    public CAOEntry()
    {
        this.TimeEntries = new List<TimeEntry>() { new TimeEntry() };
    }
    public DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime ValidTo { get; set; }
    public List<TimeEntry> TimeEntries {get; set;}
}
```

My View(the part that creates the handles the TimeEntry List)

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TimeEntries)
        <button data-bind="click: addTimeEntry">Voeg tijdsvak toe</button>
        <button data-bind="click: removeTimeEntry">Verwijder laatste</button>:
```

the data-bind"click:addTimeEntry" is a jQuery/KnockoutJs script that adds new time entries. These are added from an Editor Template.
In this Editor template i got the following line of code:

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.DayOfWeekOrHoliday,"--Selecteer een dag--", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", data_bind = "value: DayOfWeekOrHoliday, namePath: true" } })
```

Now the following happens when i have, for example two, TimeEntries filled in and click on save;
There are three time entries returned to my controller:
One containing the first filled Enum Value, other fields are null.
the other two don't contain any Enum values but have the other fields filled.

When debugging the view, i saw the following problem;

---

TimeEntry 1:
enum field;

```
id="TimeEntries_0__DayOfWeekOrHoliday" name="TimeEntries[0].DayOfWeekOrHoliday"
```

Example of a second field:

```
id="TimeEntries_1__TimeFrom" name="TimeEntries[1].TimeFrom"
```

---

TimeEntry 2:
Enum field;

```
id="TimeEntries_0__DayOfWeekOrHoliday" name="TimeEntries[0].DayOfWeekOrHoliday"
```

Example of a second field:

```
id="TimeEntries_2__TimeFrom" name="TimeEntries[2].TimeFrom"
```

---

so the Array is not incremented right for the enum value. Is this because there is an enum field in an EditorFor helper?
I can't figure out how to solve this.
[Edit]
TimeEntry Class:

```
public class TimeEntry
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    //1:Monday,2:Tuesday,3:Wednesday,4:Thursday,5:Friday,6:Saturday,7:Sunday,8:Any Holiday
    public enum Days {Maandag =1,Dinsdag =2, Woensdag=3,Donderdag = 4, Vrijdag= 5, Zaterdag=6, Zondag=7, Feestdag = 8}
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Dag")]
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Selecteer een dag")]
    public Days DayOfWeekOrHoliday { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Start Tijdvak(uur:minuten)")]
    [StringLength(5, MinimumLength = 5)]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:hh:mm}")]
    public string TimeFrom { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Eind Tijdvak(uur:minuten)")]
    [StringLength(5, MinimumLength = 5)]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:hh:mm}")]
    public string TimeTo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal Premium { get; set; }

}
```

EditorFor:

```
function createViewModel() {

        var createTimeEntry = function () {
            return {
                DayOfWeekOrHoliday: ko.observable(),
                TimeFrom: ko.observable(),
                TimeTo: ko.observable(),
                Premium: ko.observable()
            };
        };

        var addTimeEntry = function () {
            TimeEntries.push(createTimeEntry());
        };

        var removeTimeEntry = function () {
            TimeEntries.pop();
        };

        var ValidFrom = ko.observable();
        var ValidTo = ko.observable();
        var TimeEntries = ko.observableArray([createTimeEntry()]);

        return {
            ValidFrom: ValidFrom,
            ValidTo: ValidTo,
            TimeEntries: TimeEntries,
            addTimeEntry: addTimeEntry,
            removeTimeEntry: removeTimeEntry
        };
    }

$(document).ready(function () {
        var viewModel = createViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please show your code for the TimeEntries class and the code in your EditorFor.

Comment: @JamesDev I will add it above

Comment: My thoughts right now is that the @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TimeEntries) does not handle the @Html.EnumDropDownListFor() properly, any thoughts or fixes?

Comment: I have also tried to change the EnumDropDownListFor() to @Html.DropDownList("TimeEntry.Days", EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(TimeEntry.Days)),"Select My Type", new { @class = "form-control" }) This gave me the same result